# Error while validation yaml File kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I created the below ns.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
Name: testns
```

I am getting the below error.

```
error: error validating "ns.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Namespace.metadata): unknown field "Name" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: Use `name` instead of `Name`

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is clear in the error logs: `unknown field "Name" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta;`

This means you need to use `name` instead of `Name`.

For more info about YAML format of Kubernetes object Namespace metadata, run the following command :

```
kubectl explain namespace.metadata
```

And you will get amazing documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. Sure will check the documentation.